# gt_summary add_ci returning mean rather than 95% CI

Tags: r, gtsummary

When using the add_ci() function in gt_summary I get the mean returned for both CIs rather than the CIs. Where am I going wrong? These are very different from CI's calculated with the ci function from bayestestR.

Sample data and code below.

```
subset<-structure(list(subject = c(3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 16, 24, 28, 31, 1, 4, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 23, 27, 29, 32, 11, 12, 14, 18, 19, 20, 22, 25, 26, 30, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 16, 24, 28, 31, 1, 4, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 23, 27, 29, 32, 11, 12, 14, 18, 19, 20, 22, 25, 26, 30, 3, 6, 7, 8, 10, 16, 24, 28, 31, 1, 4, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 23, 27, 29, 32, 11, 12, 14, 18, 19, 20, 22, 25, 26, 30, NA), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA), levels = c("PEP", "PSP", "REO"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA), levels = c("Pre", "Mid", "Post"), class = "factor"), total_mt = c(6.05, 4.81, 7.58, 6.15, 5.71, 5.89, 5.42, 6.14, 7.54, 5.95, 6.13, 5.09, 5.95, 5.46, 4.75, 6.25, 7.54, 7.85, 8.26, 6.36, 4.9, 6.98, 6.58, 7.49, 6.79, 6.18, 7.8, 5.32, 5.39, 6.39, 6.68, 5.83, 8.55, 6.63, 6.54, 6.46, 5.47, 6.61, 7.3, 6.24, 6.13, 5.73, 6.21, 6.62, NA, 6.29, 7.7, 7.89, 8.22, 6.75, 4.97, 6.04, 7.04, 7.87, 6.85, 6.13, NA, 6.02, 5.64, 7.33, 6.17, 5.62, 9.38, 6.88, 6.49, 6.51, 5.46, 6.4, 7.35, 6.58, 6.55, 5.57, 6.99, 6.75, 5.35, 6.55, 7.73, 7.28, 8.53, 6.5, 5.18, 7.13, 7.32, 7.91, 7.28, 6.91, 7.2, 6.15, 5.65, 7.18, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -91L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(pacman)
p_load(tidyverse, easystats, emmeans, bayestestR, rstanarm, tidybayes, readODS, bayesplot, SingleCaseES, gtsummary)

## order levels

subset$group <- factor(subset$group,levels = c('PEP','PSP','REO'))
subset$time <- factor(subset$time,levels = c('Pre','Mid','Post'))

## run model

total_mt_mod <- subset %>% 
  stan_lmer(total_mt~time*group+(1|subject),data=.,warmup=1000, iter=9000)

##total muscle thickness
#posteriors

total_mt_posteriors <- emmeans(total_mt_mod,pairwise~time|group)%>%
  gather_emmeans_draws()%>%
  filter(.,time!="NA")%>%
  as.data.frame()%>%
  select(time, group, .value)

#order levels

total_mt_posteriors$time <- factor(total_mt_posteriors$time,
                                   levels = c('Pre','Mid','Post'))

total_mt_posteriors$group <- factor(total_mt_posteriors$group,
                                    levels=c('PEP','PSP','REO'))

#create table

total_mt_table <- total_mt_posteriors%>%
  tbl_strata(group,~.x %>%
               tbl_summary(by=time,
                           statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{median}",
                           missing="no",digits = all_continuous() ~ 2,
                           label=list(.value~"Total"))%>%
               modify_header(label ~ "**Muscle thickness<br>(cm)**")%>%
               modify_header(all_stat_cols()~"**{level}**")%>%
               add_ci(pattern= "{stat} ({ci})")%>%
               modify_footnote(update = everything()~NA))
total_mt_table
```

Comment: Please update your post with a minimal reproducible example, that is, code+data we can run on our machines that illustrates the issue. Second, please include what you expect the results to be.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Thank you for your reply data and code has been upload. I excepted the results to be the 95% CIs, but add_ci() is returning the mean value instead.

Comment: Thank you for updating the post! Can you include what values you think the 95% CIs should be? I see that you a referencing the bayestestR package. But if you look at the documentation, that is _not_ how the CIs are calculated in `add_ci()`. Use your data to calculate the CIs using the method indicated in the `add_ci()` documentation, and we can investigate a discrepancy if it persists. If looks like you're modelling first, then getting the CIs from there. I haven't looked into the details, but `tbl_summary()` is expecting observed data, and that is the assumption when the CIs are calculated

Comment: I see now. I was hoping to obtain the 95% credible interval rather than the confidence interval. The confidence interval calculated from the t.test method agree with add_ci(), so no discrepancy. With that said is there any way to calculate the 95% credible interval? Or is there a way to input non-integers in the {p##} argument of statistic in tbl_summary? When I add {p5}, {p95} after "{median}" I get the same output as the 90% credible interval, but would like to have 95%, which I think would be {p2.5}, {p97.5}. Either way, thank you for your help!

Comment: The p95 syntax is a built-in shortcut for the quantile function and only supports integers. But you can define any quantile function and use it in tbk_summary, eg p_lb <- function(x) quantile(x, probs = 0.025)